# Chromedriver 107 for Mac M1

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Need help or advice.
I can't find a chromedriver 107 for Mac M1. My current Chrome version 107, Selenium doesn't run tests.

Tried to install chromedriver_mac64.zip and chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Mac M1 and with the following driver everything works:
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver_mac_arm64.zip

Third file from:https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=107.0.5304.62/

```
Chrome is up to date
Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (arm64)
```

I suspect that the problem is related to configuration of the Selenium webdriver path or some security warning from macOS.

If you are hiting on the security warning, you can check this article on how to fix it:
https://thewiredshopper.com/apple-cannot-check-for-malicious-software-error/

```
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/myuser/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! Your link about security warning was useful 

Answer (score 0):

this is what fixed it for me.

1. Go to the system and preferences -> security and privacy.
2. Then under general tab you will see a notification that about the exec you are trying to open.
3. Just click "open anyway" there.
   4, Go back to the chromedriver exe and open it it will then give you the same error but along with that you will get an option to open it.
4. Click Open and it should resolve.

Worked for me.